# Review for large chunks of code

Tags: discussion, code-length

I am migrating from small pieces of code to larger applications. All my code is public on github or simillar. As I am in the middle of this transition, I am not very intrested in reviewing chunks of code (altough I know I have mistakes and will be nice to know them), but I am more intrested in reviewing the architecture of the project (starting from file structure to how functions or modules relate to each others). So it is pretty hard to do this chunk by chunk.

Let's assume the code is fully documented and I provide an overview of the architecture in my question. Also, I specify the points where I think there is a problem and I would like to get a piece of advice (of course, there may be other problems that I am not aware of).

Speaking about code size, let's consider somewhere between 2k and 5k lines, including documentation. Would a question like this be accepted by this community (by accepted I mean to get some attention too, not only to remain open)?

Comment: If it is C I will certainly look at it, however big.  But the bigger it is the more I'd like to see the architectural info you mentioned. Whether I can say anything about it that is useful is less certain...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is sort of hard to determine.  We don't get very many large projects that cannot be split up.  You may browse [code-length](/questions/tagged/code-length) if you'd like, or you may post your question anyway and we'll determine if it's too long (or possibly if an automatic flag is raised).  The worst that can happen is that it'll attract little attention, but such questions in and of themselves are not subject to closure.

Do be aware that [*Higher-level architecture and design of software systems*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are off-topic here, assuming that your code fits into that category.  If so, it'll best belong on Programmers SE.  If you want to make sure, go ahead and post your code, and it can be migrated if the community deems it off-topic.

Comment: Higher-level architecture can be reviewed, but it needs to be implemented code. See also https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1924/31562

Answer (score 10):

We don't have any limits to how much code you are allowed to post. The more code you provide, [the more description of the code should accompany it](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Be aware though that there are two limits that you need to be aware of:

- The code you want to have reviewed must be contained [within the question itself](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/can-i-put-my-code-on-a-third-party-site-and-link-to-the-site-in-my-question)
- There is a limit of 65536 characters in a Code Review post.  (Most Stack Exchange sites allow just 30000.)

What this effectively means is that you can have approximately 64kb of code in your question. If you want a review of more than this, divide it into several parts and several questions.