# Design for a question about thread abortion and related process

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I [posted a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/103763/abort-thread-on-new-request-but-complete-only-last-request) for Code Review, and other than a few comments, what I was told was that I should put actual code of the process and people were only interested in knowing that. What I really wanted was a review on design, not the implementation detail. But it was downvoted and trail of comments asking me to put actual code. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `What I really wanted was a review on design, not the implementation detail.`

That's your problem right there friend. We *want* your implementation detail. That's really the whole purpose of this site. We help you to improve the implementation of the design you've settled on and specified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm the moderator that cleaned up the 25-or-so comments on your post, and reopened your question after the `// do something` placeholders were replaced with actual code.

Thank you for coming to meta.

> *Am I missing something here?*

Yes.

Please read [**why is hypothetical code off-topic?**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/23788), which goes into the details of why the site's regulars voted to close your question and demanded to edit the actual code into the post.

About the *design*, see [**reviewing "design"**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1924/23788), which explains how the *design* is the *code*; we review code, not design; asking a boiled-down question stripped of its context and specifically looking for a "design review" is outside our scope. However when you post your actual code, and the design is wrong, it's more than likely that a reviewer will point it out - **asking** for a design review is off-topic, but **answering** can cover any and all aspects of the code, and that includes the design.