# How does a question get fewer votes than an answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

This is a review site, so the questions should be voted on whether or not they are on-topic and if they clearly portrayed their code so that it could be reviewed.

If a question has 4 answers, yes, it may be badly written code, but it still works and shows signs it can be improved.  All the answers are up voted, a lot, but the question has fewer votes than the accepted answer.

The logic escapes me.

One example: [How can I make this method shorter and easier to follow?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5450/18427)

Question = 8 votes (counting mine)
Accepted answer = 12 votes ( not counting mine )

Comment: People don't think of the asker as putting forth as much effort as the answerer.

Comment: Don't get me wrong though... +1 in the spirit of the question :)

Comment: @Timtech Upvotes on questions are worth half as many points as upvotes on answers.

Comment: @200_success Exactly. That's why I tend to upvote questions more on other sites (but there are so few of them here at code golf).

Comment: @Timtech this is CodeReview

Comment: @Malachi Whoopsies. I mix them up a lot since I have a 2nd Monitor (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a frequently asked question: [Why do questions need votes, too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122940/why-do-questions-need-votes-too) has many duplicates.

There's no consensus here on why a question should be upvoted: [see this link to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=13150551#13150551)

My voting policy is:

- **Upvote *all* answers** which I think are helpful (to thank the person who spent the time to answer)
- Downvote any answer which I think is **wrong or harmful**
- **Upvote the *fewer than all* questions** which:

  - I think or hope other people will find especially interesting
  - I find especially interesting and for which I'd like to see more answers
  - I think are especially well-asked (clearly written, researched, effort put into asking the question)
- Downvote any question which I dislike, e.g. because IMO it **cannot be answered well**, but which is good enough that I can't vote to close it

Therefore I upvote answers more frequently than I do questions (and downvote rarely).
I upvote most (not all) question that I answer myself (because I at least thought they were worth answering).

Of the three reasons I gave to upvote a question, the first two above are intended to encourage more answers to this question. The third is intended to encourage future questions from the OP.

Comment: What's a "fewer than all" question?

Comment: Contrasted with "upvote all answers", I upvote "less than all questions". For example sometimes I read a question which I didn't answer; and think, "That's a good answer" and upvote it, without upvoting the corresponding question.

Answer (score 6):

Usually on Code Review, those who answer tend to put more effort in their answer than the person who is asking the question.

To ask a question, you *can* basically copy-paste some code that you have written and ask "How can I improve this code?". That doesn't make it a **good** question.

To answer a question, you **need** to ask yourself: What is this code doing? How could it be done better? Having a lot of programming experience helps to answer a question, but the most difficult part of answering is to "BE the code". Understanding what code is doing isn't always easy.

For the question you linked here, I am down-voting it because it's a simple "copy-paste" question, the asker does not make it easier **in any way** for reviewers to answer the question. See also: [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does) . There is absolutely no explaining the code whatsoever in that question.

Comment: +1 for *BE the code*. :-)

Comment: I also like the point about the downvoting.  I usually don't vote on them since the asker *really* didn't put in any effort to make the question clear, but downvoting looks like a good option.

Comment: @Jamal Knowing what code *does* is relatively easy: you can 'interpret' the code, 'simulate' running it in your head. Knowing what the code is *meant* to be doing can be more difficult: you must reverse-engineer the functional spec, difficult if the code is badly written ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/400436/49942)). So, +1 to Simon for asking for a description of what the code does.