# How should a canonical question title be formatted on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, titles

See the following 2 questions and their title edits:

- [Calculations with a table containing football data](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12679/calculations-with-a-table-containing-football-data) ([revisions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/12679/revisions))
- [Database output function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/database-output-function)  ([revisions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/12680/revisions))

While I understand that having all questions formatted as "please help with this code", "review X" and so on, at least when I was looking at them in my history I could easily dissociate them. However, after the title edits, I had absolutely no idea what these were, and I don't think describing the code's intent is **always** relevant to the fixes needed.

So it didn't seem like an appropriate review and edit in my opinion, but as I am unaware of the right way to format these questions, I'd be happy to see the discussion around this issue and canonical examples of questions with correctly formatted titles.

---

**Update:** I found this question on Meta CR.SE, which addresses part of the issue, but the guidelines apply mostly to the question's body, not its title:

[What makes a good question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-makes-a-good-question?rq=1)

Comment: A question on edits by palacsint which has, in turn, been edited by palacsint...

Comment: @Basic: as long as it's helpful, I don't mind the irony :)

Comment: Nor me but it did make me chuckle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems to me that the only thing that makes any sense in a title is what the code does.

The two examples you show were ones that ask for code reviews. But every last question on this site is asking for a code review. So there is no point in including that in the title.

You could include the language of the code, but that's already in the tags.

You could specify what specifically you want a review of, but most of the time you really just want a general code review.

So I think the titles that @palacsint has been adding are exactly the titles we should have.

Comment: ok, good to know.